# Словообразование слова изъян

Tags: словообразование

добрый день. Ищу информацию по словообразованию и этимологии слова "изъян".

Answer (score 1):

Слово "изъян", с одной стороны, соотносится со словом "изъять", а с другой стороны, может быть заимствовано из персидского языка, где zijan обозначает "вред, убыток". В этом случае слово считают переоформлением в результате сближения.

Comment: Спасибо, София! Если я правильно понял, изъ является приставкой?

Comment: Да, ИЗ  - это приставка. Исторический корень индоевропейского характера  ЯТЬ/ИМАТЬ встречается во многих современных словах: взять, снять, съёмка, объём, неотъемлемый и др.

Comment: Благодарю!